# Could someone explain the difference between ggplot and geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting the same data 2 separate ways, and I thought the resulting figures would be the same because they both make use of `geom_point`; however, they are quite different. Does anyone know what differs between these sets of commands? In both cases, I am trying to plot data with three color classes. My guess is that the first way just plots the sets of colors separately with alpha only considered for points from the same class.

**plotting each set of colors separately**

```
g1 <- ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(data = df[df$color==1, ],
             mapping = aes(x=A, y=B), col = "grey", alpha = 0.05,) + 
  geom_point(data = df[df$color==2, ],
             mapping = aes(x=A, y=B), col = "red", alpha = 0.05) + 
  geom_point(data = df[df$color==3, ],
             mapping = aes(x=A, y=B), col = "blue", alpha = 0.05)
```

[image]

**plotting the points together**

```
g2 <- ggplot(df,
             mapping = aes(x = A, y = B, colour = color)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.05) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey", "red", "blue"))
```

[image: g2]

Comment: My guess is that the plotting order is different. If you rearrange `df` by color they will match up. Things get draw one geom at a time, so the top one has the blue points drawn last. Within a geom, the ordering of the data.frame matters, I think top rows get drawn first.

Comment: When you add layers, each one goes on top of the last. So the first way you plot all the grey points first, then you plot all the red points on top of that, then you plot all the blue points on the very top. I'm not 100% sure, but I think when you have a single layer they get plotted in row order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirming what was said in comments. A single layer will be plotted in row order. Here's a demonstration

```
dd = data.frame(
  x = c(1:4, 4:1) / 4,
  y = rep(c(1, 1.25), each = 4),
  group = rep(letters[1:4], 2),
  id = 1:8
)

dd
#      x    y group id
# 1 0.25 1.00     a  1
# 2 0.50 1.00     b  2
# 3 0.75 1.00     c  3
# 4 1.00 1.00     d  4
# 5 1.00 1.25     a  5
# 6 0.75 1.25     b  6
# 7 0.50 1.25     c  7
# 8 0.25 1.25     d  8

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(x, y, color = group)) +
  geom_point(size = 60, show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_text(aes(label = id), color = "black")
```

[image]

From the overlaps, you can see that each subsequent row is plotted on top of the previous values.

Thus, when you plot separate subsets, whatever you plot first (all the grey points) will be on the bottom, and so forth, with the points you plot last (blue) on top. When you plot all at once, they will be plotted in whatever order they appear in your data.